# MS Access 03 Query Criteras

Tags: ms-access-2003

If I have a report that tracks data for several accounts for each month with rows labeled:

```
UNITS, 
REVENUE,
AVG REV/UNIT
```

How would I create a query that will filter the report to just show accounts where the UNITS row has increase/decreased 25% and the AVG REV/UNIT has increased/decreased 10%, from the previous month to the current month.

An example would be for the month of June I have the numbers....

```
            JUN
UNITS       3,271
Revenue     $3,598.10
Avg R/U     $1.08
```

So when I run the report at the end of July I only want accounts that have a 25% difference in UNITS and/or a 10% difference in AVG REV/UNIT to show on a report.

```
qryPharmacy
SELECT PHAR_REPORT.*, (IIf(u1 Is Null,0,u1)+IIf(u2 Is Null,0,u2)+IIf(u3 Is Null,0,u3)+IIf(u4 Is Null,0,u4)+IIf(u5 Is Null,0,u5)+IIf(u6 Is Null,0,u6)+IIf(u7 Is Null,0,u7)+IIf(u8 Is Null,0,u8)+IIf(u9 Is Null,0,u9)+IIf(u10 Is Null,0,u10)+IIf(u11 Is Null,0,u11)+IIf(u12 Is Null,0,u12)) AS USUM, (IIf(r1 Is Null,0,r1)+IIf(r2 Is Null,0,r2)+IIf(r3 Is Null,0,r3)+IIf(r4 Is Null,0,r4)+IIf(r5 Is Null,0,r5)+IIf(r6 Is Null,0,r6)+IIf(r7 Is Null,0,r7)+IIf(r8 Is Null,0,r8)+IIf(r9 Is Null,0,r9)+IIf(r10 Is Null,0,r10)+IIf(r11 Is Null,0,r11)+IIf(r12 Is Null,0,r12)) AS RSUM, RMonth.*, PG2.*, PG.pGroup
FROM PHAR_REPORT, RMonth, PG2, PG
WHERE (((PHAR_REPORT.PR) Like ([PCODE] & '*')) And ((PG.pID)=PG2.PID))
ORDER BY PG2.pID, PHAR_REPORT.PR;
```

Comment: Can you include the SQL Query you are currently using to get the above numbers? The table schema would slightly help as well.

Comment: @ktharsis does that help out?

Answer (score 0):

You should do it with more than one query. In the first query, select the data for the first month. On a second, to the desired month to compare. Create a third query that links the two first (be care about the correct relationship). Do the grouping/calculations in these queries.

In the 3rd query, create two fields that calculates increasing/decreasing for units and rev/unit. Now, you can add a criterium on each parameter field in the query columns.

The chalenge here is to be sure about hou would you work with the primary keys on months. Eg: if a A row in the first query isn't in the second (for not having an event on second month, for example), it will not be showed. In this case, the solution would be to create the queryes linking a table or query wich has the entyre set of registers, forcing it to show all the desired records despite they have or not occurrences.